# iCheck plugin not working correctly on ipad and iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, icheck

I was searching for some custom checkboxes made with jQuery and i run into `http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/` plugin. It seems perfect and it acts perfect on web, but there is a little issue on ipad and iphone.

**Problem**: when i click on a checkbox, something is blinking (ins element) and it look very bad. I need it to work like it's working on the web. Can anybody help please?

Ps. Usually i search for other solutions, but this plugin really seems great besides that problem, it has lots of functions and i really want to use it.

Update: you can test it directly on any checkbox from this page : `http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/` from an ipad or iphone. One thing that i found out now is that i see that background appear and disapear quickly on any element not only on checkboxes, on texts to.

Comment: If it's working on the demopage for the plugin, and that plugin seems to be working for everyone else, it most likely is something you're doing wrong, and without any explanation other than "it's blinking", and no code, how are we supposed to help you ?

Comment: That is it, id does not work on the demo page. Check it again. I am testing there also. Check it with your ipad or iphone.

Comment: If the plugin doesn't work as intended on the demo page, and you have the same issue, the developer probably wasn't able to fix it, and you'll have to contact whoever made the plugin and ask why, as you can't possibly expect us to fix something that the developer couldn't based on a short explanation of what the problem is. It's either that, or find another plugin!

Comment: 1. Do you think it is possible he did not see the bug? 2. It is possible that you are a better developer than him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent
```

will solve your problem.

Comment: Can you please provide the example